# Populating relationships between POCO classes in EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship, poco

I am trying to setup seeding for a project that pulls data from an existing data. The part that is giving me trouble is how to setup the relationships between the tables as I import the data.

```
I have three tables:
1) Patient
2) InsuranceProvider
3) Doctors
```

Basically, the Patient has an Insurance Provider, and the Insurance Providers each have several Doctors the patient can choose from. I have setup the following entities.

```
public class Patient
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int LegacyInsuranceProviderId {get; set;}
  public int InsuranceProviderId {get; set;}
  public virtual InsuranceProvider insuranceProvider {get; set;}
}

public class InsuranceProvider
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int LegacyId {get; set;}
  public string CompanyName {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Patient> patients {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Doctor> doctors {get; set;}
}

public class Doctor
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string DoctorFullName {get; set;}
  public int LegacyInsuranceProviderIdId {get; set;}
  public int InsuranceProviderId {get; set;}
  public virtual InsuranceProvider insuranceProvider {get; set;}
}
```

The classes all have a field called "Legacy..." this represents the previous primary keys of the respective tables. I am doing this so I don't lose track of the relationships since new primary keys will be generated for each table.

What I cannot figure out is how to populate the relationships between these classes.

Comment: You have a typo in your Doctor class with the field `LegacyInsuranceProviderIdId `.

Comment: Thanks ... fixed that

Comment: Is it as simple as looping through the patients and doctors, fetching the insurance provider into the navigation property (var provider = context.InsuranceProviders.Single(ip => ip.LegacyId == currentPatient.LegacyInsuranceProviderId;) then saving the changes? I'd probably do it with a SQL script versus Seed().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup you have looks good to me.

The `virtual` keyword used notifies entity framework that that field is a "navigation property". It can use this information to load the data when querying by constructing a join between the two. All you have to do is access the join and it will populate the data. There are two ways.

Let's just assume we are inside of a using block (or injected class) which has `db` as an already instantiated object of your DbContext.

The **first way** would be through lazy loading. The `doctorPatients` variable here is going to now hold a list of that doctor's patients. *Note: if the db has been disposed, lazy loading will cause an exception to be thrown.*

```
var doctor = db.Set<Doctor>().Find(1);//get a Doctor by primary key
var doctorPatients = doctor.insuranceProvider.patients;
```

The **second way** would be through eager loading. This uses the `Include` method which instructs the query to join when fetching data and will as a result return the relevant information.

```
var doctorWithPatients = db.Set<Doctor>.Include(d => d.insuranceProvider.patients).Find(1);
```

Comment: It seems to me what you have shown is how to query once the data is filled. But I am not sure how to link the separate tables since when importing they will have a new Identity Id. The LegacyId fields have the relationship but I am not sure how to go using the new keys.